# Getting error : Error Code: 0x80070643 (1603)

Tags: sql-server

While am installing SQL server development version am getting an error as follows:

> There was an unexpected failure during the setup wizard. You may review the setup logs and/or click the help button for more information.

I checked in the log file and get the error code as

> 0x80070643 (1603)

I checked in MSDN site and get it is because of invalid folder arrangment. So i created Servers and Tools folder and copy the files to both folders. and try to install it again.

THen also am getting the same error.

Please help someone.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916760

Comment: Check this out http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916760

Comment: i do the same what explained there. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

First please understand that this is an microsoft error, it has nothing to do with your internal software problems.

This problem will not go away in 1 day. You just have to update the sytem as per the lastest update, go to settings >update > run the update and install all the updates related to windows. 
Keep your system open whole day and keep it connected to internet and all the updates will be installed after you  start installing updates.

Then run the troubleshooter or donwload from below link :-
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter

and run it until the problem go away. It will take 2-3 days at most, or it could go away the same day if you have a good internet connection and better system.